# How to say "Are you nuts?"

Tags: slang, colloquial-language

Can the following expression be used to express shock of person's actions or statements:

> 気が変になったか。

What are the equivalents to "Are you nuts?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「気{き}が変{へん}になったか。」 makes sense and it is not bad at all, but that plain か-ending makes it sound a little stiff.

You could say:

「正気{しょうき}で言{い}ってるの？」

「頭{あたま}おかしいんじゃない？」

「気が狂{くる}っちゃったんじゃないの？」

「気は確{たし}か（なの）？」

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how much used is 気が変. But I have personally never heard it.

The most accurate expression I can think of now would be :

> 頭がおかしい

You could also use :

> 馬鹿{ばか} - 阿呆{あほう}

Which are useful to express shock after someone do something dangerous or stupid.